# populate a select list full of dates based on a range from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I have a bunch of dates in a database that i want the user to be able to select a specific day from a drop down list.

I tried just listing all the dates, but this doesn't work because it shows duplicate dates.

```
$query1 = "SELECT order_date FROM orders";
$result1 = mysql_query($query1);
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
  {
    $dateDB = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($row1['order_date']));
    $niceDate = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($row1['order_date']));

?>
    <option value="<?php echo $dateDB; ?>"><?php echo $niceDate; ?></option>
<?php
  }
?>
```

How can i grab the lowest date, highest date and just populate the select box with everything inbetween ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> I tried just listing all the dates, but this doesn't work because it shows duplicate dates.

If that is the core of the problem then the simplest way to fix it would be to alter your query to use the [`DISTINCT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/distinct-optimization.html) keyword, in combination with the [`ORDER BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html) keywords to get them ordered, like so:

`SELECT DISTINCT order_date FROM orders ORDER BY order_date`

Which means you'll only get unique dates, and the first date will be the lowest and the last will be the higest, which you can easily add into your while loop.

Edit: Although if you want to do with the highest and lowest, you can use the built in [`MIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min) and [`MAX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max) functions to get the highest and lowest, and then generate them as follows:

```
<?php
    $query = 'SELECT MAX(order_date) AS `highest`, ' . 
                    'MIN(order_date) AS `lowest` FROM orders';
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $lowest = strtotime(mysql_result($result , 0, 'lowest'));
    $highest = strtotime(mysql_result($result , 0, 'highest'));
    $dates = array();
    $dateTime = $lowest;
    do
    {
        $newDates = array();
        $newDates['db'] = date("d/m/Y", $dateTime);
        $newDates['nice'] = date("d/m/Y", $dateTime++);
        $dates[] = $newDates;
    }
    while($dateTime <= $highest);
    foreach($dates as $date)
    {
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $date['db']; ?>"><?php echo $date['nice']; ?></option>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: Didn't seem to work, I still get all the dates. The times are also stores in the datetime column so im guessing it wont work because all the times are different ?

Comment: I tried you edit but i don't get any result back, Does it matter that the column "order_date" is a datetime field so it also includes the time? but i don't want that displayed in the select list.